# Saving and Loading an mlr Model

Tags: r, multilabel-classification, mlr

I've been able to successfully generate a model to assist in my multilabel assignment using the mlr library using the following setup,

```
scene.task = makeMultilabelTask(data = training.data, target = labels)
lrn.br = makeLearner("classif.rpart", predict.type = "prob")
lrn.br = makeMultilabelNestedStackingWrapper(lrn.br)
mdl.lrn <- train(lrn.br, scene.task)
```

I went about saving my model using the following line,

```
save(mdl.lrn, file = "mdl.rda")
```

The model that is saved is just over 1GB in size.

I have attempted to load that saved model using the following line,

```
load("mdl.rda")
```

However, I continually run out of memory space as I receive messaging that reads, `Error: cannot allocate vector of size ### Kb`.  I believe that my current amount of memory would allow for the loading of the model as it was enough to generate the model.

Has anyone been able to save and load an mlr generated model for reuse?  If so, would you be able to recommend or confirm the approach of saving and loading a model?

Comment: Have you tried with a smaller model?

Comment: This has been the smallest model I have been able to create with my original model sized at 3.5GB.  As an update, I've gone and spun up a virtual machine with 244GB of RAM and have just been able to load the model.  From reviewing the system diagnostics, the amount of RAM in use, after the load, is 80GB.  Does that seem out-of-line with a 1GB saved model to take up that amount of RAM?

Comment: No, that's entirely possible. The large size is probably at least in part because of the wrapper; maybe you could use another approach for multilabel classification?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  Unfortunately, I'm not aware of any other approaches other than what has been presented within the readme's of the mlr repo.  I'm open to any suggestions if you happen know of any.  

What I find interesting is that when it comes to training the model, I don't see that kind of RAM being consumed.  It's rather puzzling.

Comment: It would help if you could describe what exactly you're trying to achieve :)

Comment: Very true! I'm working with a single text entry field that can have one or more of a universe of 368 labels applied to it. My training dataset comes in at 78,000 rows. I have applied a feature hash to the text column and I have been able to get very good results from using the MultilabelNestedStackingWrapper.

Comment: Have you tried any other multilabel approaches?

Comment: Try `saveRDS()` and `readRDS()`. These functions only save and load the model, not the whole environment.

Comment: I've actually had to take revisit the data sample and attempt different multilabel approaches.  I have attempted the saveRDS as you suggested, and I can see some reduction in the object saved.  This definitely could have been the route if I had stayed on the same path I was on earlier.  Thank you!